# chef problems installing packages

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have written a very simple recipe.

```
package "mysql-server" do
end
```

whenever I run chef-client on the node, it points to that particular line in my recipe and gives FATAL errors.

However, when I go directly to the node and run

```
yum install mysql-server
```

It run successfully. Has anyone of us been through the same situations before? Replies will be appreciated.

Comment: Go through https://learn.chef.io you need all the bases

Comment: And for stackoverflow part, see [tour], and read [ask] to avoid being off topic.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a duplication of the following bug report in the chef issue tracker:

https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/2109

You most likely want to use the mysql or mariadb cookbooks to install the service correctly for now.